# Get request through postman with JWT

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have installed `pip install djangorestframework-jwt`

i have modified settings to

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
),
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
),
```

}

I have got a token by giving my credentials and then passing that token through bearer token in authorization in postman

When I do a api call through postman it gives me error saying

```
{
"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

The api call is for a BookViewSet.

Why does it say details not provided after giving the token also.

plz help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `authorization` header in Postman as `JWT <your_token_here>`.

See the `curl` example in http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/:

> $ curl -H "Authorization: JWT your_token"
>   http://localhost:8000/protected-url/

Comment: Thanks, It helped me.